# Unsure about this review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed a review audit just now, although I disagree with the outcome.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15875752

I voted to close for Off Topic > Why isn't this code working:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

My reasoning:

- Only a vague explanation of the problem is included
- No code in the question
- The pastebin link is dead
- Non-reproducable in its current form
- Poorly worded title

If my assessment is incorrect I'm happy to learn from it, however I suspect this audit might be a bad egg.

Comment: I would have chosen the same. The question is in my opinion unsolvable without looking into the linked document. Having an accepted and upvoted answer that didn't, according to the comments, fix the problem also looks strange.

Comment: @gnat Happy to close as dupe, just wanted to raise in case moderator intervention was necessary.

Comment: it's good that you brought it to meta anyway. As a result of [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601) that slippery question has got a bunch of votes down and close which dropped it off the audits

Comment: 20 helpful votes.  In the [android] tag no less, a tag were just about nobody ever votes.  And you are not sure.  Really?  You never once asked or answered a question in [android], why do you think you can review any Q+A in that tag?  Please stop reviewing, this is doing *way* too much damage.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip

Comment: @HansPassant: *"Why do you think you can review any Q+A in that tag?"* Because reviewing does not require any expert knowledge. Do you really want to say that this question is fine as it is? Since op did exactly what he should do, I don't exactly see what you want to say.

Comment: @HansPassant Irrespective of the tag, the question was a bad one and used for an audit. That's what I was unsure about, whether or not this should be raised with a moderator. To answer your question, I think I can review any question on the site against the asking guidelines, the subject matter doesn't factor into it. If I really don't understand to the point where I can't make a judgement then I will skip. Also, I will not stop reviewing, who made you the king?